# Necesito obtener el valor de un input con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos por alguna extraña razón no estoy obteniendo el resultado de mi input..Ayudenme resolviendolo por favor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
        <button type="button" id="btn">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

codigo javascript

```
var name = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(name);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer paso es registrar el evento click una vez cargue el DOM de la página.
Segundo es obtener el value actual del input dentro del evento click.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var name = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
      alert(name);
   });
});
```

Comment: Gracias...tu comentario me ayudo a entender el problema..pero va más alla de registrar el evento..creo que se me paso la logica de que para que un evento funcione..la obtención del valor deben estar contenidas dentro del evento.

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que **tu código no es dinámico**, estás recogiendo el dato una sola vez y cuando lo recoges el `input` no tiene nada, luego, aunque see cambie el contenido del `input` no  se muestra en el `alert` porque no lo estás obteniendo dentro de la función de escucha.

Generalmente lo que se hace es crear la referencia al elemento fuera, una sola vez y dentro de la función de escucha usas esa referencia para obtener el valor.

```js
var elName = document.getElementById("nombre");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(`Cada vez que cambies el contenido se mostrará el dato correcto al hacer click. El valor es: ${elName.value}`);
})
```

```html
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
        <button type="button" id="btn">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Pero el value le doy cuando doy click al button no? si no que sentido tendría que sea un formulario?

Comment: @KarlosYalta sí, pero tu código no era dinámico, revisa la edición de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! creo que la respuesta esta en la lógica que para obtener el valor de cualquier input este debe estar contenido dentro del evento..ejemplo..
Primero debo hacer el evento
Segundo debo obtener el dato que se introdujo.
Tercero..mostrar!

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var name = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
      alert(name);
   });
```

Comment: Para generar el codigo más corto..ya que hay personas que quizas como yo..necesitan de otras opciones también..eso alimenta nuestra curiosidad

Comment: Ya aceptaste una respuesta, no tienes por qué auto-responder. Como consejo, se considera una mala práctica usar `document.getElementById` dentro de funciones que van a repetirse, es mejor crear las referencias a los elementos una sola vez, fuera de la función.